# Problem with addidentity services, usermanager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identity

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[MyWebsite.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'MyWebsite.Controllers.AccountController'.

I get this error when accessing / Account / Register

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();0
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
```

Class User

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Account Controller

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
```

I'm new, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a service for `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()`

When you have created a new `User` Model

So you have to add the service for that Model `services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()`

**Edit**

Making sure you have the `IdentityRoles` service working

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()`

Comment: Now i have it -----  InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

Comment: @pitten that now means somewhere you are trying to inject `UserManager<IdentityUser>`

Comment: I fixed it, thanks! But now I have a problem again :( Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'MyWebsite.Controllers.AccountController'.

Comment: Now it looks like this    services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Comment: Very grateful! Thank. Removed Default and it worked.